# Выдает ошибку помогите!

Tags: python, бот, pycraft

ImportError: cannot import name 'client' from 'pycraft'
Как решить ошибку?

```
from pycraft import client

username = 'bot'
server_address = 'Server'

client = client(server=server_address)
```